# How to update NPM depricated fsevents?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I tried to install nodemon using cmd in git Bash: npm install -g nodemon, above warning I received. So, What is the solution for this ??

**$ npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x**

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install --quiet --no-progress
```

Will keep warnings and errors, and suppress th progress bar on terminals that support it.